# Why am I getting a black screen and my TextButtons are not working in Flutter AlertDialog?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to alert a user that the duration of the video they're trying to upload is too long by displaying an alert message and allowing the user to click an 'Ok' button to close the alert and return to the screen they were on (so they can try a different video).

I'm able to see the AlertDialog, but there is a black screen behind it and the 'Ok' button is not clickable/has no action. There are no errors showing in my console. I'm guessing it has something to do with the context I'm passing, but I haven't been able to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the relevant code:

```
getVideoDuration(BuildContext parentContext, controller) {
    final duration = controller.value.duration.inSeconds;
    isLongVideo = duration > 60;
    setState(() {
      isLongVideo;
    });
    if (isLongVideo) {
      return showDialog(
          context: parentContext,
          builder: (context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: const Text("Error"),
              content: const Text(
                  "Video exceeds 60 seconds. Try uploading a different video."),
              actions: <Widget>[
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 'Cancel'),
                  child: const Text('Cancel'),
                ),
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 'OK'),
                  child: const Text('OK'),
                ),
              ],
            );
          });
    }
  }

  buildUploadForm() {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white70,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black),
          onPressed: clearImage,
        ),
        title: const Text(
          "Caption Post",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
        actions: [
          TextButton(
            onPressed: isUploading || isLongVideo ? null : () => handleSubmit(),
            child: Text("Post",
                style: isUploading || isLongVideo
                    ? TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 20.0)
                    : TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.blueAccent,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 20.0)),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          isUploading ? linearProgress() : const Text(""),
          Container(
            height: 220.0,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
            child: Center(
              child: FutureBuilder(
                  future: _initializeVideoPlayerFuture,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                        getVideoDuration(context, _controller);
                      });
                      return AspectRatio(
                        aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                        child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
                      );
                    } else {
                      return const Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                    }
                  }),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: widget.currentUser!.photoUrl != ""
                  ? CachedNetworkImageProvider(widget.currentUser!.photoUrl!)
                  : AssetImage('assets/images/default_profile.png')
                      as ImageProvider,
            ),
            title: Container(
              width: 250.0,
              child: TextField(
                controller: captionController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Write a caption...",
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                ),
                minLines: 1,
                maxLines: 8,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Divider(),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(
              Icons.pin_drop,
              color: Colors.orange,
              size: 35.0,
            ),
            title: Container(
              width: 250.0,
              child: TextField(
                controller: locationController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Where was this photo taken?",
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: 200.0,
            height: 100.0,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: ElevatedButton.icon(
              onPressed: () => getUserLocation(),
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.my_location,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              label: Text(
                "Use Current Location",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                ),
                backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          // Wrap the play or pause in a call to `setState`. This ensures the
          // correct icon is shown.
          setState(() {
            // If the video is playing, pause it.
            if (_controller.value.isPlaying) {
              _controller.pause();
            } else {
              // If the video is paused, play it.
              _controller.play();
            }
          });
        },
        // Display the correct icon depending on the state of the player.
        child: Icon(
          _controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```